# What is the appropriate way to multithread LevelDB in Go?

Tags: database, multithreading, go, leveldb, levigo

I have implemented the levigo wrapper in my project so I can use LevelDB.  The declaration is fairly boilerplate, like so:

```
func NewLeveldbStorage(dbPath string) *leveldbStorage {
     opts := levigo.NewOptions()
     opts.SetCache(levigo.NewLRUCache(3<<30))
     opts.SetCreateIfMissing(true)
     log.Debugf("Entering Open")
     db, err := levigo.Open(dbPath, opts); if err != nil {
         log.Fatal("BOOM %v", err)
     }
     log.Debugf("Finished calling open")
     opts.Close()
     return &leveldbStorage{db:db}
 }
```

Here is the struct returned:

```
type leveldbStorage struct {
     db *levigo.DB
}
```

I then made a few simple GET and STORE commands on the struct that essentially just use `s.db.Get` and `s.db.Put`.  This works fine in my tests, but when I run the following benchmark:

```
 func BenchmarkLeviDbGet(b *testing.B) {
     s := storage.NewLeveldbStorage("/path/to/db")
     value := "value"
     uid,_ := s.Store(value)

     b.ResetTimer()
     for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
         s.Get(uid)
     }
```

This benchmark, when run, returns:

```
 2014/10/12 21:17:09 BOOM %vIO error: lock /path/to/db/LOCK: already held by process
```

Is there an appropriate way to use levigo/leveldb to enable multithreaded reading?  What about writing?  I would not be surprised if multithreaded writing is not possible, but multithreaded reading seems like it should be.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you close db after `BenchmarkLeviDbGet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either need to close the database file or use a global instance to it, you can't open the file multiple times, you can however access the same instance from multiple goroutines.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood the benchmark setup; I thought it was going to run the things in the `for` loop continuously, but it in fact runs the whole procedure continuously.